# Bash ls a folder through a variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script and I want to `ls` a directory. The path is written in a separate file which I am importing with `source`. When I execute with

```
#!/bin/bash

source Settings
echo $PathToLaunchers
echo "Availible launchers"
ls -f --color \$PathToLaunchers
```

In my Settings file is:
    `PathToLaunchers="~/Games/Minecraft/Launchers"`

It says

```
ls: cannot access $Path: No such file or directory
```

when it should `ls` the directory that the value holds. How can I make it `ls` the directory given by the variable?

Comment: Can you show us more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `\` in front of `$PathToLanuchers`.

It is escaping the `$` which causes bash to not expand the variable.

The command should be

```
ls -f --color $PathToLaunchers
```

You also need to remove quotation marks from around `~/Games/Minecraft/Launchers` This tells bash that you want a literal tilde or If you want the home directory replace it with $HOME

```
PathToLaunchers=~/Games/Minecraft/Launchers
```

or

```
PathToLaunchers="$HOME/Games/Minecraft/Launchers"
```